# Set Mongoose model instance properties with "extend" util

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have Mongoose model instance:

```
var s = new Song({
  song_id: '123',
  title: 'sample song',
  artist: {
    name: 'sample artist',
    id: '456'
  }
});
```

Now I'd like to set/update its properties but using `extend` (e.g. from nodejs util._extend)

```
s = extend(s, {
  title: 'changed title',
  artist: {
    name: 'changed artist',
    id: '789'
  }
});

s.save();
```

And while `title` (as a top-level property) gets set ok, changes in `artist` are not visible.

I know I can just set it via:

```
s.artist.name = 'changed artist';
```

but is there something I'm missing or is this way of updating properties not usable?

**EDIT**

Gah... Looks like someone defined schema the wrong way. Instead of `artist` field defined as

```
artist: {
  name: String, 
  id: String
}
```

it was defined like

```
artist.name: String, 
artist.id: String
```

When I redefined it it works now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to use Mongoose's update method:

```
Song.update({
    song_id: '123',
}, {
    $set: {
        title: 'changed title',
        artist: {
            name: 'changed artist',
            id: '789',
        },
    },
}, function(err, numAffected) {
    ...
});
```

However, I don't actually see why your extend attempt failed. It seems to work for me, I usually use underscore's _.extend function.

Comment: Gah... Looks like someone defined schema wrong. instead of `artist: {name: String, id: String}` it was defined like `artist.name: String, artist.id: String`. When I redefined it it works now. Thanks